# How to modify module.exports globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, module.exports

I am trying to create a logger that will log something before all method calls (like performance tracking).

I am using JS decorators for this , the class and method decorator is like :

**logger.ts:**

```
//class decorator with code to apply log to all class methods
export async function logger(something): Promise<void> {
  doSomething
}

// decorator
export async function logMethod(something): Promise<void> {
  console.log()
  something.apply(this,args)
}
```

in files with class i can use it as :

**someclass.ts**

```
@logger
export default class SomeClass extends BaseClass {

  async somemethod(message: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return "Hi";
  }
}
```

But for non class methods i cannot use decorator. So i created a proxy object which does the same :

```
logProxy = function() {
  return new Proxy(object, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        console.log()
        //do something

      }

}
```

I use this proxy in non class files as :

**somefile.ts:**

```
export async function dosomething(): Promise<void> {
  const endPoint = `${url}`;
  await get(endPoint);
}

module.exports = logProxy(module.exports);
```

I have to do this for many files , is there a way to or better way to ensure module.exports calls the proxy for all import globally , or a way to over ride module.export such that

`module.export = log(module.exports);` , when ever its called

Comment: Why are you mixing ESM with CommonJS in **somefile.js**?

Comment: @m its a .ts file , corrected the typo

Comment: I don't get why that makes a difference. You are intentionally mixing module systems for some (not recommended) reason.

Comment: @morganney could you suggest another way i could use it for non class files ?

Comment: Your question and use case is really unclear. I am only interested in pointing out the obvious issue with this question, there's too much to unravel here for me.

Comment: @morganney i reworded the question also thank you for commenting , do let me jnow if i need to add more information